# Class loader not finding form class

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to create a custom form in my drupal 8 instance, and I have followed a few different tutorials, but every time I try to go to the forms path I see the following error on the page:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

When I check my apache log, I see it came because of this error:

Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Class "Drupal\report_service_call\Form\ReportServiceCallForm" does not exist." at /var/www/html/abcnj/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php line 24

I do have my ReportServiceCallForm set up at the following path under my module:

lib/Drupal/report_service_call/Form/ReportServiceCallForm.php

this is the contents of that file:

```
<?php
/**
 *@file 
  *Contains /Drupal/report_service_call/Form/ReportServiceCallForm
  */


  namespace Drupal\report_service_call\Form;

  use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
  use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
 /**
  *Implements Drupal form Interface
  */
 class ReportServiceCallForm extends FormBase{

 /**
  *{@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function getFormID(){     
     return 'report_service_call_form';
  }
 /**
  *{@inheritdoc}
  */
public function buildForm(array $form, array &$form_state){
  $form['company_name'] = array(
    '#type'=> 'textfield',
    'title'=> $this->t('Company Name')
  );

$form['cotact_name'] = array(
  '#type'=> 'textfield',
  'title'=> $this->t('Contact Name')
);

$form['current_system_type'] = array(
  '#type'=> 'textfield',
  'title'=> $this->t('Current System Type')
);

$form['telephone_number'] = array(
  '#type'=> 'tel',
  'title'=> $this->t('Telephone Number')
);

$form['email'] = array(
  '#type'=> 'email',
  'title'=> $this->t('Email Address')
);

$form['service_request'] = array(
  '#type'=> 'textfield',
  'title'=> $this->t('Service Request')
);

$form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
    '#button_type'=>'primary',
);
return $form;
}

  /**
  *{@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, array &$form_state){

  }

 /**
  *{@inheritdoc}
  */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, array &$form_state){

  }
}
```

Also I have the contents of my routing.yml as follows:

```
report_service_call.form:
    path: '/Customer-Service/Report-Service-Call'
defaults:
  _title: 'Report Service Call Form'
  _form: 'Drupal\report_service_call\Form\ReportServiceCallForm'
requirements:
  _permission: 'access content'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file needs to be located at `[MODULE FOLDER]/src/Form/ReportServiceCallForm.php`

Comment: You were right, I changed to this and it worked. Must have been using outdated documentation/tutorials. Thanks!